# deep list remove in Racket with lambda

Tags: racket

I need to create a procedure that takes 2 inputs. The first is a test procedure and the second is a list.

As output, it produces a List that is a copy of the input List with all of the elements for
which the test procedure evaluates to true removed.

Note the input list could be deep list.

for example

```
(deep-list-remove (lambda (x) (= x 0)) (list 0 1 2 3))
;returns (1 2 3)
```

Or

```
(deep-list-remove (lambda (x) (< x 4)) '(7 2 (3 4 (5 6))))
;returns '(7 ( 4 (5 6)))
```

I have tried with

```
(define (deep-list-remove f list)
  (for/list ([i list]
             #:unless (f (f i))))
             i             
  )
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7enq.png)

but I get the following error

> =: contract violation
> expected: number?
> given: #t

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using a recursive function:

```
(define (deep-list-remove f lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((cons? (car lst))
         (cons (deep-list-remove f (car lst)) (deep-list-remove f (cdr lst))))
        ((f (car lst)) (deep-list-remove f (cdr lst)))
        (else (cons (car lst) (deep-list-remove f (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and your time, it helped me a lot.